# Do we still need to hide/remove print statements in Xcode 8.2 and Swift 3 when releasing app?

Tags: swift, printing, release

Is it still recommended / needed to hide print statements when releasing an app with Xcode 8.2 and Swift 3?

At the moment I have a global print function like this

```
 func print(_ items: Any...) {
    #if DEBUG
        Swift.print(items[0])
    #endif
}
```

than will only print if the project is in Debug mode.

Apple recently finally added the DEBUG flag by default in Xcode so we do not have to manually add it anymore in OtherFlags in Build Settings.

This made me wonder if we actually still need to remove the print statements or does Swift/Xcode do it automatically or is there some other optimisation where it is no longer needed.

If not is the above way the best approach?

Comment: I can see my print statement in a console even when running from release schema. Tested in Xcode 10.1, Swift 4.2. Looks like we still need to remove them, thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After doing some more research it still seems that we need/should hide print statements for release. As mentioned in my question its best done via a global print function

```
func print(_ items: Any...) {
    #if DEBUG
        Swift.print(items[0])
    #endif
}
```

Comment: do you add this in app delegate and do you call it in didFinishLaunching?

Comment: Just in a swift file or outside any class.

Comment: but don't you have to call it somewhere?

Comment: Your print statements with now call this function automatically.

Comment: Its works like charm, but i am not getting why Any... as parameter, could you explain.

Comment: Its any so that you can print anything like Strings, Integers, Doubles, Arrays, Dictionaries, etc, just like the native swift print function does.

Answer (score 2):

```
import Foundation

class print {
   @discardableResult init(_ Item: Any) {
        print(Item)
    }

   private func print(_ item: Any) {
    #if DEBUG
        Swift.print("HI + \(item)")
    #endif
    }
}
```

-> Open Build settings -> Swift compiler-Custom flag -> Other swift flag.
-> expand the  Other swift flag -> Add -D DEBUG before debug.
create new class name print and just add the code. It will bypass the prints.

Comment: How to call into objects?